# Convert multiple variables from char to numeric

Tags: sas

I have been working on converting a number of variables in my table to numerical types from characters. I discovered the method to alter one variable and can continue doing so for each variable. However, I wanted to solicit SE because I am having trouble developing a sustainable solution.

**How can I edit multiple variables at once in SAS Studio 3.5?**

My attempt thus far:

What works:

```
data work.want(rename=(age_group='Age Group'n));
  set work.import;
  age_group=input('Age Group'n,8.);
  drop 'Age Group'n;
run;
```

What doesn't work:

```
data work.want(rename=(age_group='Age Group'n), rename=(dwelling_type='Dwelling Type'n));
      set work.import;
      age_group=input('Age Group'n,8.);
      dwelling_type=input('Dwelling Type'n,8.);
      drop 'Age Group'n, 'Dwelling Type'n;
    run;
```

Comment: What does this mean: "doesn't work"? Read your log. You want an array to handle multiple conversions.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your RENAME statement is incorrect. I don't recommend using that type of variable notation though, so I'm going to suggest labels instead. To convert multiple variables use an array. You do have to list them out once at least though, in the array statement.

```
data work.want;
  set work.import;
  array num_vars(*) age_group dwelling_type;
  array char_vars(*) 'Age Group'n 'Dwelling Type'n;

  do i=1 to dim(num_vars);
       num_vars(i) = input(char_vars(i), 8.);
  end;

  label age_group = 'Age Group'
        dwelling_type = 'Dwelling Type';

run;
```

If you wanted to do a RENAME as a dataset option, you would do it as follows, no comma's and the keyword rename once.

```
(rename=(age_group='Age Group'n dwelling_type='Dwelling Type'n));
```

Comment: This was my first time using SAS and I have been scouring the internet for resources. I have been reading my log, but I don't know how to correct my errors. Thus, I asked for help.

Comment: There is an abundance of resources here: http://support.sas.com/training/tutorial/ and lexjansen.com - search for your topic of interest.